# Getting {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} with one sample, but not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to take the results from some questionnaire, the results are then sent to some API to be scored and results are returned, upon successful return of the results they are saved as an object to the Entity.

Here is my code: (Non-important data replaced with stars)

```
internal static List<ScreeningTool> GetSurveyResults(OpenCase openCase, int screeningToolId, short screeningId)
    {
        using (var cmDb = new DBEntities())
        {
            var currentScreeningTool = cmDb.ScreeningTools.Find(openCase.CaseId, screeningToolId, screeningId);
            var SFClient = new Core.OptumSurveySF10.amIhealthySoapClient();

            var Key = "*******************************";
            var GroupId = *****;
            var GroupLogin = "*******";
            var SurveyId = *****;
            var SiteLogin = "*************";
            short AdministrationType = 5;
            var AdministrationDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            short SessionType = 3;
            var Age = (DateTime.Today.Year - openCase.BirthDate.Value.Year - (openCase.BirthDate.Value.DayOfYear > DateTime.Today.DayOfYear ? 1 : 0));
            var DOB = openCase.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            var Gender = "";

            if(screeningToolId == 15)
            {
                SurveyId = 52304;
                var GH01_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 1).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var PF02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 3).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var PF04_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 4).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var RP02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 6).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var RP03_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 7).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var RE02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 9).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var RE03_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 10).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var BP02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 11).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var MH03_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 13).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var VT02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 14).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var MH04_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 15).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var SF02_Response = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 16).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var MH01_Response = -1;
                var MH02_Response = -1;
                var MH05_Response = -1;
                var HT_Response = -1;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                var results = SFClient.SF12v2Session(Key, GroupId, GroupLogin, SiteLogin, SurveyId, AdministrationType, AdministrationDate, SessionType, openCase.CaseId, "", "", "", Gender, GH01_Response, PF02_Response, PF04_Response, RP02_Response,
                        RP03_Response, RE02_Response, RE03_Response, BP02_Response, MH03_Response, VT02_Response, MH04_Response, SF02_Response, MH01_Response,
                        MH02_Response, MH05_Response, HT_Response, "", "");
                   

                if (results.Scored)
                {
                    var pcsFormat = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(results.PCSScore, 2));
                    var mcsFormat = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(results.MCSScore, 2));
                    var pcs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", pcsFormat);
                    var mcs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", mcsFormat);

                    var screeningToolAnswer17 = new ScreeningToolAnswer();
                    screeningToolAnswer17.CaseId = openCase.CaseId;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.ScreeningToolId = screeningToolId;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.ScreeningId = screeningId;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.InfoInsertId = currentScreeningTool.InfoInsertId;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.InfoInsertTime = DateTime.Now;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.InfoChangeId = currentScreeningTool.InfoInsertId;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.InfoChangeTime = DateTime.Now;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.QuestionId = 17;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.AnswerId = 1;
                    screeningToolAnswer17.AnswerText = pcs;


                    var screeningToolAnswer18 = new ScreeningToolAnswer();
                    screeningToolAnswer18.CaseId = openCase.CaseId;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.ScreeningToolId = screeningToolId;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.ScreeningId = screeningId;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.InfoInsertId = currentScreeningTool.InfoInsertId;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.InfoInsertTime = screeningToolAnswer17.InfoInsertTime;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.InfoChangeId = currentScreeningTool.InfoChangeId;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.InfoChangeTime = screeningToolAnswer17.InfoInsertTime;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.QuestionId = 18;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.AnswerId = 1;
                    screeningToolAnswer18.AnswerText = mcs;

                    cmDb.ScreeningToolAnswers.Add(screeningToolAnswer17);
                    cmDb.ScreeningToolAnswers.Add(screeningToolAnswer18);
                    cmDb.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else if(screeningToolId == 14)
            {

                var FirstName = "";
                var LastName = "";
                var MemberLogin = openCase.CaseId;

                var GHGLOBALResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 1).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First();
                var PFSOMEResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 3).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var PFBENDResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 4).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var RPKINDResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 5).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var REBKINDResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 6).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var BPGLOBALResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 7).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var SEFRIENDResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 8).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var SEOVERALLResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 9).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var MHUPSETResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 10).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;
                var BEGLOBALResponse = currentScreeningTool.ScreeningToolAnswers.Where(x => x.QuestionId == 11).Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(); ;

                var result = SFClient.SF10R1Session(Key, GroupId, GroupLogin, SiteLogin, SurveyId, AdministrationType, AdministrationDate, SessionType,
                            MemberLogin, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Age, Gender, GHGLOBALResponse, PFSOMEResponse, PFBENDResponse,
                            RPKINDResponse, REBKINDResponse, BPGLOBALResponse, SEFRIENDResponse, SEOVERALLResponse,
                            MHUPSETResponse, BEGLOBALResponse);

                if (result.Scored)
                {
                    var phs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", result.PHS10Score);
                    var pss = String.Format("{0:0.00}", result.PSS10Score);

                    var screeningToolAnswer12 = new ScreeningToolAnswer();
                    screeningToolAnswer12.CaseId = openCase.CaseId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.ScreeningToolId = screeningToolId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.ScreeningId = screeningId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoInsertId = currentScreeningTool.InfoInsertId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoInsertTime = DateTime.Now;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoChangeId = currentScreeningTool.InfoChangeId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoChangeTime = screeningToolAnswer12.InfoInsertTime;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.QuestionId = 12;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.AnswerId = 1;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.AnswerText = phs;


                    var screeningToolAnswer13 = new ScreeningToolAnswer();
                    screeningToolAnswer13.CaseId = openCase.CaseId;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.ScreeningToolId = screeningToolId;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.ScreeningId = screeningId;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.InfoInsertId = currentScreeningTool.InfoInsertId;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.InfoInsertTime = screeningToolAnswer12.InfoInsertTime;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoChangeId = currentScreeningTool.InfoChangeId;
                    screeningToolAnswer12.InfoChangeTime = screeningToolAnswer12.InfoInsertTime;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.QuestionId = 13;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.AnswerId = 1;
                    screeningToolAnswer13.AnswerText = pss;

                    cmDb.ScreeningToolAnswers.Add(screeningToolAnswer12);
                    cmDb.ScreeningToolAnswers.Add(screeningToolAnswer13);
                    cmDb.SaveChanges();
            }

            return cmDb.ScreeningTools.Where(x => x.ScreeningToolId == screeningToolId && x.CaseId == openCase.CaseId && x.ScreeningId == screeningId).ToList();
        }
    }
```

For some reason the conditional of `ScreeningToolId == 15` works just fine, im able to submit multiple questionnaires no problem but when `ScreeningToolId == 14` i get `{"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}` Looking at ValidationErrors wasnt much help.

When I looked that up it was mentioned everywhere to wrap the `cmDb.SaveChanges();` in a try block so I wrapped it in:

```
try
                    {
                        cmDb.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
                    {
                        foreach(var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                                eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                            foreach( var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                    ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                        throw;
                    }
```

which returns a message of "OriginalValues cannot be used for entities in the Added state." and
`'(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult>(($exception).EntityValidationErrors).Items[0]).Entry.OriginalValues' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

Which should be one of the two outputs from the try/catch block. but im not seeing the other one. and the exception its displaying doesnt make sense to me. How can `DBContext.SaveChanges()` not be a valid operation?

Sorry if i am missing vital information, if you need anything more let me know and ill add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `screeningtoolanswer13` is defined there are two lines with a typo that say `screeningtoolanswer12` instead. This is what caused the issue. fixed the typo and now it works flawlessly.